# destroyed folder now without directory attribute

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card

I tried to read some videos from the memory card of my digital camera. It wasn't possible to access the DCMI Folder, 
because there was no directory attribute. The expecting DCIM folder was a 0-byte file. 
After typing "ls -l" I get a list of folders/files on the memory card and the first colum of the DCIM-Folder was not "d" but "-".

Any idea to recover the files? Is there a way to just set the the directory attribute for the DCIM-File?

Comment: Show us the ls -l. There are Windows viruses that rename the main directory to another name...

Comment: Thanks for answering. I didn't use the memory card with Windows. I can send you the exact output from "ls -l" later. I used the memory card with my linux pc in the morning, at this moment everything was ok. During the day, I used my camera to film. A view hours later I tried to copy the data to my computer, but the DCIM folder was a 0-byte file in the filesystem and there were no videos on the memory card (not even in other directories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filesystem is damaged. Just because you've identified one byte that's damaged doesn't imply that the rest is fine, in fact it's rather the opposite. There's a good chance that making the directory entry back into a directory will make the filesystem invalid, or will make the directory contain junk.

The first thing you need to do is make a copy of the SD card to a file, and work on that copy. Under Linux, assuming that the SD card is `/dev/sdb`:

```
sudo cat /dev/sdb >/var/tmp/videos.sdcard
cp /var/tmp/videos.sdcard /var/tmp/videos.fsck.sdcard
```

Then try a filesystem repair on that second copy:

```
/sbin/fsck.fat /var/tmp/videos.fsck.sdcard
```

Try mounting that: `sudo mount -o loop /var/tmp/videos.fsck.sdcard /mnt` or `fusefat /var/tmp/videos.fsck.sdcard ~/mnt`.

If it didn't help, make another copy `/var/tmp/videos.manual-repair.sdcard` and try modifying it with a hexadecimal editor (preferably one with knowledge of the FAT filesystem; [Active@ Disk Editor](http://disk-editor.org/) looks like it might help but I've never used it). As I wrote before, I wouldn't set my hopes up.

If you can't manage to repair the filesystem, you can try retrieving images and videos with forensic tools such as [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) and [PhotoRec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhotoRec).